# .net сериализация

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

Всем привет. На учебе дали такое задание. Но я совсем не понимаю логику и не понимаю как начать. Остановился на том, что создал 4 класса, как указано. 
1 Абстрактный и 3 наследника.

Что дальше делать нет мыслей. Подскажите, пожалуйста, буду очень благодарен за наводку.

```
public abstract class BaseHolder
{

}

public class IntHolder : BaseHolder
{ 

}

public class CharArrayHolder : BaseHolder
{ 

}
public class DoubleHolder : BaseHolder 
{ 

}
```

И не пойму совершенно по какому принципу разделяется в дереве, как в примере.

А главное, что должно получиться в итоге? текстовый или xml файл с данными? или аналогичное дерево?

Пожалуйста, не пинайте, рад любой помощи.

UPD. 
Какие варианты могут быть визуализации задания?

Comment: Вам еще рано задаваться здесь вопросом сериализации, для начала нужно определиться как хранить данные.

Comment: В самом задании не указано, как их хранить. Я так предполагаю, что в итоге не должно получиться такого структурированного дерева визуально, а какой-либо файл. Иначе мне не дали бы такое задание)
А если файл, то думаю это должен быть xml.

Comment: Если не указали в каком формате хранить, то храните в каком душе угодно, хоть в excel'е

Comment: С форматом определились. Надеюсь на вашу дальнейшую помощь

Comment: @ВасилийФедоров Что Вы понимаете под словами "визуализация задания"?

Comment: @Igor То, как можно это визуализировать. Прикрутить интерфейс. Какой-то. Получится, ведь вывести, например данные из файла деревом? Мб текстом структурным или еще как то

Comment: Вариант - запись в Memo с отступами.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Отделим данные от древовидной структуры:

```
public abstract class BaseHolder
{
    public abstract object BaseValue { get; }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return BaseValue.ToString();
    }
}

public class IntHolder : BaseHolder
{
    public int Value { get; set; }
    public override object BaseValue { get { return Value; } }
}

public class CharArrayHolder : BaseHolder
{
    public char[] Value { get; set; }
    public override object BaseValue { get { return Value; } }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Join("", Value);
    }
}

public class DoubleHolder : BaseHolder
{
    public double Value { get; set; }
    public override object BaseValue { get { return Value; } }
}

public class HolderNode<T>
{
    public T Data { get; private set; }
    public List<HolderNode<T>> Children { get; private set; }
    public HolderNode(T aData)
    {
        Data = aData;
        Children = new List<HolderNode<T>>();
    }
}
```

Тест:

```
class Program
{
    private static void WriteNode(HolderNode<BaseHolder> aNode, int aLevel)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < aLevel; i++)
            Console.Write("    ");
        Console.WriteLine(aNode.Data.ToString());

        for (int i = 0; i < aNode.Children.Count; i++)
            WriteNode(aNode.Children[i], aLevel + 1);
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // создание дерева как на картинке
        HolderNode<BaseHolder> root = new HolderNode<BaseHolder>(new IntHolder() { Value = 1 });

        HolderNode<BaseHolder> _2011 = new HolderNode<BaseHolder>(new IntHolder() { Value = 2011 });
        HolderNode<BaseHolder> fulcrum = new HolderNode<BaseHolder>(new CharArrayHolder() { Value = "FULCRUM".ToCharArray() });
        fulcrum.Children.Add(new HolderNode<BaseHolder>(new CharArrayHolder() { Value = "LINUX".ToCharArray() }));
        fulcrum.Children.Add(new HolderNode<BaseHolder>(new IntHolder() { Value = 7 }));
        _2011.Children.Add(fulcrum);
        root.Children.Add(_2011);

        root.Children.Add(new HolderNode<BaseHolder>(new CharArrayHolder() { Value = "C++".ToCharArray() }));

        HolderNode<BaseHolder> pi = new HolderNode<BaseHolder>(new DoubleHolder() { Value = 3.14 });
        pi.Children.Add(new HolderNode<BaseHolder>(new CharArrayHolder() { Value = "TEST".ToCharArray() }));
        pi.Children.Add(new HolderNode<BaseHolder>(new IntHolder() { Value = 9 }));
        pi.Children.Add(new HolderNode<BaseHolder>(new IntHolder() { Value = 6 }));
        root.Children.Add(pi);

        // рекурсивный вывод в консоль
        WriteNode(root, 0);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Консольный вывод:

```
1
    2011
        FULCRUM
            LINUX
            7
    C++
    3.14
        TEST
        9
        6
```

Comment: Можно немножко комментариев? Почему этот код написан именно так и какие у него плюсы/минусы?

Comment: @tym32167 Шутите? Какие минусы :)?

Comment: :D я просто подумал, что автору доставит мало пользы, если просто скинуть ответ без каких-либо пояснений

Comment: Автор просто сидит и гуглит непонятные вещи))

Comment: @ВасилийФедоров Что требует пояснений в коде ответа?

Comment: А зачем вам  BaseValue? Лишняя сущность, функциональной нагрузки никакой, только запутает человека

Comment: @PrimusSingularis -Василий Алибабаевич, зачем тебе червонец? -Нада!

Comment: @igor Подскажите, я так понял, вы отредактировали пример. Это только для отделения данных от дерева? А наоборот нужны еще классы? Или можно на основе этого и данные в дерево преобразовывать? 
Просто я сижу еще разбираюсь во всем. Пока не особо понимаю весь алгоритм.

Comment: @igor огромное спасибо за помощь. Теперь думаю, что больше не будет вопросов.

Answer (score 0):

В каждом из ваших классов напишите по два поля, условно:

```
object data;
BaseHolder parent;
```

Соответственно, у корня дерева `parent` будет равен `null`, а у других элементов ссылаться на родителя.

После этого любой сериализатор в любом формате сохранит все нужные данные (а десериализатор, соответственно, восстановит).

Примеров той же самой XML-сериализации чуть больше, чем очень много.

Comment: Ловушка? Не `parent`, а `children`.

Comment: А логика наполнения какая должна быть? Или ее в задании не заложено, и нужно просто наполнить и выводить в файл или тянуть назад? 
По сути, как я понял из сети интернет, что в такой структуре должна быть какая то логика.

Comment: "я понял ..., что в такой структуре должна быть какая то логика" - +1000

Comment: Очень попрошу не тролить. Вернулся с армии и восстановился. Сейчас дали задание такое. Нужно сделать до пятницы. А у меня в голове только "так точно". Напрочь все забыл.

Answer (score 0):

Для сериализации лучше не использовать object, тем более что есть базовый класс, так будет выглядеть система классов:

```
[DataContract]
public abstract class BaseHolder
{
    [DataMember]
    public BaseHolder[] Children {get; set;}
}

[DataContract]
public class IntHolder : BaseHolder
{
    [DataMember]
    public int Val {get; set;}
}

[DataContract]
public class CharArrayHolder : BaseHolder
{
    [DataMember]
    public char[] Val {get; set;}
}

[DataContract]
public class DoubleHolder : BaseHolder 
{ 
    [DataMember]
    public double Val {get; set;}
}
```

Для хранения лучше всего использовать xml, так же можно добавить генерализацию. Для корректной сериализации лучше всего использовать DataContractSerializer. После декларации типов для сериализации можно использовать штатный XmlSerializer...